# Returning row number from array with duplicate values

Tags: excel, match, lookup

I need to find out who "sold" the train(s) in the simplified example below.
There are multiple train entries, but for now, they are only allocated to a single salesperson.
The columns extend at least to EE - not to E as in this example.

My initial thoughts were to match the train entry to a row ( or rows ) and then lookup the row number from a predetermined row assignment helper table, i.e. Sales02 corresponds to Rows 7 - 11 and a row result value equal to 7 ( perhaps `MIN()` would work here ) would return Sales02, but the fact that the lookup data spans multiple columns makes things a bit difficult.

Any ideas on returning "Sales02" from the "train" query?

[image]

Comment: I'm confused by your ask.  You're just looking to find who has the most entries of "train" in your list?  `A2=CountIfs(B2:E6,"train")`, which can be copy/pasted into `A7` and `A12`.  If you wanted to use a helper sheet, you could have a list of products (train, car, etc.), and create a combobox that you want to work with, so you could have a combobox in `A17` that you pick "train" from the drop down, then all the `CountIfs()` reflect `A2=CountIfs(B2:E6,$A$17)`.  You can then determine which SalesTeam has the highest count and, voila, an output has been reached.

Comment: If that is the incorrect assumption, please update the post to be very clear... note that using `Match()` will output the first row entry, so I don't think that will help you with what is described.

Comment: I used a very simple example, but should have stated train01, train02, train03, etc.    The question would then still be: Who sold Train train02?   The method described below concatenates the salesman, trainXX and wkXX data into a column, filters to unique values, and then runs Xloopup to find out who sold that specific train n that specific week.  Finding how many trains was sold is not really applicable.   To clarify, the concatenate function used a fixed reference for sales02, i.e. $A:$11

Answer (score 0):

Not really an elegant solution, but it works.

I imported the dataset into a helper sheet, where I combined the cell value with the corresponding value in Column A for each row ( a name in this case ) and the date from row 1 for each column, using underscore as a delimiter.

This new data range was then given a unique name, EE in this case.

On a second helper sheet, using this formula `=INDEX(Filtered,1+INT((ROW('Sheet1'!C3)-1)/COLUMNS(Filtered)),MOD(ROW('Sheet1'!C3)-1+COLUMNS(Filtered),COLUMNS(Filtered))+1)` and drag it down till it returns an REF! error and going back one row before the error.

This transposes all the data into a single column G. Using `=UNIQUE(SORT(FILTER(B3:B3240,B3:B3240<> "","")))`  then gives me a filtered list of unique values in column H that I then run

`=IF(H3="","",LEFT(H3, SEARCH("_",H3,1)-1))` for the first data value in I, and

`=IF(H3="","",MID(H3, SEARCH("_",H3) + 1, SEARCH("_",H3,SEARCH("_",H3)+1) - SEARCH("_",H3) - 1))` for the middle data value in J, and

`=IF(H3="","",IFERROR(TEXT(RIGHT(H3,5),"yyyy-mm-dd"),"NF"))` for the last data value in K.

Then just run XLOOPUP across columns I, J and K to get the data your looking for.